# Rails assets controller serves public assets instead of assets' index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails app, I have an assets controller (Since the requirement of the model name is Asset).

I use 
`resources :assets`
to route my controller to this URL to display /assets.

Everything works fine in the development mode. However, after I deployed the application on AWS Beanstalk, it displays Error 404 from Nginx.

After going through Nginx error log file in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, I found this.

```
open() "/var/app/current/public/assets" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.31.21.101, server: _, request: "GET /assets?status=active HTTP/1.1"
```

What I understand from the log, it means the application tries to look for assets  `/var/app/current/public/assets` instead of `GET /assets` route.

Therefore, my question is, how can I make the application serve the assets folder the view file? Or is there any workaround? One solution I can think of is changing the assets folder to something else.

Comment: nginx is redirecting the request before it hits your app, meaning any changes you make to the rails app won't take effect

Comment: Can you post your nginx conf file please?

Comment: I think this might cause because of name `asset` you are using.
You can try debugging on your local by running the app in `production` env & `precompiling` rails assets.

Comment: @Mark Is this the issue?

`        location /assets {
          alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;

          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS';
        }`

This is in my .ebextension conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a name collision of the routes you're creating.

As of default, rails assets are stored in `public/assets`. Rails then tries to use [xsendfile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) (if you have it correctly configured) to deliver the given asset from the public directory.

To avoid these collision, you can either change your RESTful route to a name other than `:assets` or you can customize the asset prefix with this code:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.prefix = '/some_other_path'
```

EDIT: I highly recommend to rename the RESTful route, because some poorly written gems do not use assets.prefix but the hardcoded `/assets` path. Nested routes could be also fine if it is possible. (Thanks to Gabor Garami)

Comment: I highly recommend to rename the RESTful route, because some poorly written gems do not use `assets.prefix` but the hardcoded `/assets` path. Nested routes could be also fine if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added prefix but nevertheless the load balancer tries to load from the public/assets folder before the route. Therefore, I decided to change psuedo-naming the route by using `resources :asssets`. Only downside is I wouldn't be able to use the convention for forms. At least, I can understand the naming and it solves my problem. Up for you!